# Ubuntu. No Ethernet. No wireless. No optical drive. How to install wireless drivers?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

Got a PC, I had to build it myself. Now, it doesn't have an optical drive, so I can't just put the disk with the drivers in and get them in. I also don't have ethernet or wireless internet due to me not having those drivers. I really need the help.

Comment: Can you edit to post to include the results of the following commands in terminal? `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` `lsusb` `lsmod` as it will help

Comment: If you have optical CD or DVD containing drivers, you could insert it on another optical-drive-owned PC. Then, copy those driver files to any USB. Later, insert that USB into your PC and install the drivers from it. Note: Make a backup of the drivers.

Comment: I do have an optical CD containing the drivers I for the motherboard. I did try what you said a few days ago but it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 1):

If it has a USB drive you can install drivers from another computer, but I don't know where you could download them.

Comment: How do I install drivers from another computer? All help is appreciated! :D